# Name of this effect / How to reproduce it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I would like to use this effect:

[image: effect circle]

It's a circle focusing the user on a special part of the application.

It also has a pulsaring white smaller circle.

[image: effect pulsing]

Is there a Standard Android effect out there? I've already seen such a thing somewhere else.
Anyhow, I would appreciate it to get some code on how to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this effect by using third-party android libraries. One of them is [FancyShowCaseView](https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView).

It uses Circular reveal animation and you can easily use it in an AndroidX project by adding the following:

```
implementation 'me.toptas.fancyshowcase:fancyshowcaseview:1.2.1'
```

If the project doesn't incorporate AndroidX, then use:

```
implementation 'me.toptas.fancyshowcase:fancyshowcaseview:1.1.5'
```

A sample usage has been provided in their github repo. Please follow the link associated with the library name. Hope this helps.

[image]   [image]

Another one is [TapTargetView](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView). This suits more to your required effect I assume. Please have a look here in the following at the end of this gif of the search button:

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for this very quick answer! Really didn't expect such a quick and quality response on this special topic. That deserves the Checkmark and thank you for giving me reputation :)

Comment: @Tester2389 Please view my updated answer, I think I have added a better, more suitable suggestion for you with demo which would preferably suit your tailored requirement. And thanks & I would appreciate if you accept this as your answer if this helps in any way.

Comment: Yes, perfect, I just came from the toilet and thought oh wait I would need something that will stay there longer to as well display some text and awesome you have found the excact thing I was searching for. Thank you again :)

Comment: Sounds great. Please accept the answer as well by clicking the tick mark on the left if my effort has helped - I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Yes, I had to wait about 10 minutes, therefore I hadn't ticked it already

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Feature Discovery](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/growth-communications/feature-discovery.html).  Not sure that there are any standard Android effects for that but there are tons of libs on [android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/198)

Comment: Oh, your solution seems to be useful as well. I will check that one out as well, thank you very much